# All mail from import went directly to spam folder in Gmail

Tags: gmail, import

I have 2 gmail accounts, for example: user1@gmail.com and user2@mydomain.com (using Google apps).

On user2@mydomain.com I went to settings: Check mail from other accounts: and added user1@gmail.com

After doing so, all the emails from user1@gmail.com were moved and transferred directly to user2@mydomain.com but went all into the spam folder as you can see here:

User1 Inbox:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/B5SNHZX.png]

User2 Inbox:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/cPR2Y3a.png]

Obviously this is a HUGE problem because the emails going to spam will be automatically deleted. My question is, how can I reverse this process and get all those emails in spam back to user1@gmail.com as they were before?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to your `Spam`, `Select All` and hit the `Not spam` button.

[image: not-spam]

Comment: There was not much else I can do, as Google support was no help either so I decided to make a new folder called Old Mail and move the spam into it. Thanks

Comment: Can you please tell to me what happened to the labels (_"folders"_ as you called them) of the messages that were moved from User1 to User2 and then to the  spam folder? **1.** Labels were NOT transferred. **2.** Transferred as new labels in User2 and .... **2a.** They are still there in User2 or **2b** They vanished when emails were moved to spam. **Also**. (about User1): **3**. I still have access to User1 account. **4**. (if so) I expect new emails to be arriving and will need to move them over as well (or not).

Comment: The labels from User1 did not transfer to User2 unfortunately. Luckily it is an old account that I wanted consolidated so it's not that big of a deal, makes it a little bit less organized but w/e.

Comment: @Goose "_The labels from User1 did not transfer to User2 unfortunately_". I guess that is the worst part. As for the future, make sure that under `Accounts and Import` -> `Check email from other accounts` you follow (as mentioned at [Get all messages](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289) **Step 1: Change the settings in your other account** -> **Recommended:** Next to "When messages are accessed with POP," select **keep Gmail's copy in the inbox**. It will insure a safe backup in case something goes wrong during the transfer.

Comment: This answer is unviable when transferring thousands of emails.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to add user1 as a google contact at user2, so that it gets treated a a trusted source? Maybe gmail considered it spam because a lot of e-mails were forwarded from user1 to user2 in a short amount of time.

If adding the contact doesn't work, make a filter giving those emails a label, that way they'll be easy to find.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Or create a filter never to send to spam?